# Explaination of RayWenderlich's CCParallaxNodeExtras.h

Tags: android, cocos2d-x, game-engine, raytracing

I was going through the [Ray Wenderlich's Space Game](http://www.raywenderlich.com/33752/cocos2d-x-tutorial-for-ios-and-android-space-game) tutorial for android.
Great Tutorial.
I am an intermediate C++ programmer and I am trying to understand what's happening inside here.
Just to understand I've rewritten it. Removing macros.

```
class CCPointObject: CCObject 
{
 protected:
      CCPoint m_tRatio;
      CCPoint m_tOffset;
      CCNode *m_pChild; 
 public:

virtual CCPoint getRatio() const
{
    CCLog("getRatio_CALLED");
    return m_tRatio;
}

virtual void setRatio(CCPoint newRatio)
{
    CCLog("setRatio_CALLED");
    m_tRatio = newRatio;
}
    .
    ..
    ...
    // similarly getChild/setChild/getOffset/setOffset is defined. The code works perfectly fine.
};

void CCParallaxNodeExtras::incrementOffset(CCPoint offset,CCNode* node)
{
    for( unsigned int i = 0; i < m_pParallaxArray->num; i++) 
    {
        CCPointObject *point = (CCPointObject *)m_pParallaxArray->arr[i];
        CCNode * curNode = point->getChild();
        if( curNode->isEqual(node) ) 
        {
            point->setOffset( ccpAdd(point->getOffset(), offset) );
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

MY DOUBTS:

- when point is initialized (by casting CCObject* to CCPointObject*), how m_tOffset, m_tRatio and m_pChild is initialized to actual values of that Object's offset and ratio ?
- I've given CCLogs in setOffset/getOffset functions of CCPointObject, but they have been never called so which setOffset/getOffset is called ?
  As CCPointObject is inherited from CCObject so I thought, might be CCObject's setOffset/getOffset is being called but, as i checked, there is no setOffset/getOffset declared in CCObject.
- I looked in to ccParallaxNode.h and its there,

  //array that holds the offset / ratio of the children

  CC_SYNTHESIZE(struct _ccArray *, m_pParallaxArray, ParallaxArray)

  and _ccArray has CCObject** that means Array of CCObjects and CCObject does not  have any variable as m_tOffset/m_tRatio or m_pChild so, where actually the offset/ratio is stored ?

These doubts are driving me nuts. Please help !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Type casting is to tell the compiler that the object to the right side of `=` is a type of object which is on the left side of `=`. So there is no initialization taking place here. We are not creating a new object, simply **type casting** it by which compiler assumes that the object belong to that class.

2)Following is the definition of `CCPointObject` class

```
class CCPointObject : CCObject
{
    CC_SYNTHESIZE(CCPoint, m_tRatio, Ratio)
    CC_SYNTHESIZE(CCPoint, m_tOffset, Offset)
    CC_SYNTHESIZE(CCNode *,m_pChild, Child)    // weak ref

    static CCPointObject * pointWithCCPoint(CCPoint ratio, CCPoint offset)
    {
        CCPointObject *pRet = new CCPointObject();
        pRet->initWithCCPoint(ratio, offset);
        pRet->autorelease();
        return pRet;
    }
    bool initWithCCPoint(CCPoint ratio, CCPoint offset)
    {
        m_tRatio = ratio;
        m_tOffset = offset;
        m_pChild = NULL;
        return true;
    }
};
```

Dont know exactly where did you put the log but. `setOffset` and `getOffset` are defined implicitly inside the macro `CC_SYNTHESIZE`. No doubt these will be called, otherwise the complier raises an error or the app will crash during runtime.

3)`CC_SYNTHESIZE(struct _ccArray *, m_pParallaxArray, ParallaxArray)`
Here `m_pParallaxArray` is used to store `CCPointObject`, where each `CCPointObject` holds information of exactly one child of parallax node, i.e reference to the child itself `m_pChild` and `m_pChild` `m_tRatio`

You can see definition of `CCPointObject` class in `CCParallaxNodeExtras.cpp` and `CCParallaxNode.cpp`

Comment: Now when I looked in to CCparallaxNode.cpp, There's a class CCPointObject and indeed, m_pParallaxArray stores CCPointObject. What I can't understand is that the CCPointObject is not visible in CCParallaxNodeExtras.cpp so, to get the access,we declare another CCPointObject keeping the data members same (even the variable names are same but member functions are not exactly same) and after casting it gives the object of Original CCPointObject. I mean, can we really do that? just redefine the class with same name and data member and typecast to get the original object.

Comment: Is that a concept of C++ that I dont know? and if we can do this then the structure of entire class (including member function) shouldn't be same?

Comment: @BitKnight For this you can take c, c++ `structures` as examples, in this it does not matter what name you give to the variables, but if the number of variables, there types and orders are same then you can cast it to any other structure. It holds good in this case also. But it is not **good practice** and **not safe**.

Comment: Thank you Souandios, Its been great help in clearing my doubts. I'll surely look in to this type of casting.